# How can I control "Access this computer from the network" / SeNetworkLogonRight from the domain controller?

Tags: active-directory, security

I need to set the "Access this computer from the network" / SeNetworkLogonRight right for all computers in a given domain.
What I would like to achieve is that only users added to the "Users" (or a more privileged group) of a machine can authenticate on that machine (not talking about interactive logon but network logon).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can set that via Group Policy. You can also use Group Policy to modify the membership of local groups.